# How can I delete a custom signing certificate created earlier

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api?tabs=http%2Cpowershell-script to automate SSO for the snowflake application

I have used

`Option 1: Create a signing certificate in Azure AD`

to create a signing certificate earlier but I want to delete it using API call.

How can I delete the signing certificate using the API call.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation the self-signed signing certificate is composed of the `keyCredential` object and the `passwordCredential` object which are added to the `servicePrincipal`.

So, you need to remove `keyCredentials` and `passwordCredentials`.

When you call

```
POST /servicePrincipals/{id}/addTokenSigningCertificate
```

it returns a `selfSignedCertificate` object and creates a new `keyCredential` object and a new `passwordCredential` object.

All the objects `keyCredential`, `passwordCredential` and `selfSignedCertificate` have the same value of `customKeyIdentifier` property.

The `keyCredential` object will be added to property `keyCredentials` on `servicePrincipal`.

The `passwordCredential` object will be added to property `passwordCredentials` on `servicePrincipal`.

## Remove

Now you need to remove `keyCredential` and `passwordCredential` objects with the same value of `customKeyIdentifier` property.

To remove the `passwordCredential` object call

```
POST /servicePrincipals/{id}/removePassword
Content-type: application/json

{
    "keyId": "{key_id}"
}
```

The correct `keydId` is for `passwordCredential` object with `customKeyIdentifier` value equals to `customKeyIdentifier` returned when you called `POST /servicePrincipals/{id}/addTokenSigningCertificate`

To remove the `keyCredential` object call

```
POST /servicePrincipals/{id}/removeKey
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "keyId": "{key_id}",
    "proof":"{proof}"
}
```

The correct `keydId` is for `keyCredential` object with `customKeyIdentifier` value equals to `customKeyIdentifier` returned when you called `POST /servicePrincipals/{id}/addTokenSigningCertificate`

Documentation

[Add token signing certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-addtokensigningcertificate?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Service principal: Remove key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-removekey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Service principal: Remove password](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-removepassword?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[passwordCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordcredential?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[keyCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/keycredential?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: But /servicePrincipals/{id}/addTokenSigningCertificate returns only public key part of the certificate. In order to remove key you need proof, which requires private key.

Comment: @MacKarczewski Yes, the proof is mentioned in the request body and link to the sample to generate a proof is in the doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-rollkey-prooftoken?tabs=csharp Private key can be stored in Azure Key Vault, etc. What are you missing in the answer?

Comment: POST /servicePrincipals/{id}/addTokenSigningCertificate returns only the public key. Therefore, it is not possible to delete a certificate created in this way using GraphAPI because the private key needed to generate the certificate cannot be recovered. To store your private key in Key Vault, you must first obtain it.